# Getting odd results from double variables (C)

Tags: c, math, double

So I have this code that is meant to calculate a total price and then give them a discount and finally present them with the total price with and without the discount. For some reason, however, I get really weird results from the calculations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
double discountPercentage=0.0;
double numbUnits=0.0, perUnitPrice=0.0, priceWDiscount=0.0;
printf("Input # of units purchased:");
scanf("%lf", &numbUnits);

printf("Input pricer per unit:");
scanf("%lf", &perUnitPrice);

if (numbUnits*perUnitPrice >= 1000.0 && numbUnits*perUnitPrice <= 2000.0)
{
    discountPercentage = 0.10;
}
else if (numbUnits*perUnitPrice >= 2000.0 && numbUnits*perUnitPrice <= 3000.0)
{
    discountPercentage = 0.15;
}
else if (numbUnits*perUnitPrice >= 3000.0)
{
    discountPercentage = 0.20;
}
else 
{
    discountPercentage = 0.0;
}

priceWDiscount = (numbUnits*perUnitPrice) - (numbUnits*perUnitPrice*discountPercentage);
double price = numbUnits*perUnitPrice;

printf("Without discount your price would be %d.\nIncluding discount (%d) your price is %d"), price, discountPercentage, priceWDiscount;

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input # of units purchased:50
Input pricer per unit:50
Without discount your price would be 266310.
Including discount (266310) your price is 2126139392
```

So what am I doing wrong? I've tried searching the forum but couldn't find anything that would help with my issue. Any help appreciated. 
Also, sorry if it's a really obvious problem but to me it isn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're computing stuff in double precision, but only printing it in integer precision.

In your `printf` statement, change all your `%d` to `%lf`.

You also close your printf statement too early with a bracket. You need to move it to the end just before the semi colon so that the `printf` actually knows what variables it's supposed to be printing.

So in total you need to change this:

`printf("Without discount your price would be %d.\nIncluding discount (%d) your price is %d"), price, discountPercentage, priceWDiscount;`

To this:

`printf("Without discount your price would be %lf.\nIncluding discount (%lf) your price is %lf", price, discountPercentage, priceWDiscount);`

Comment: Without discount your price would be 0.000000.
Including discount (-92559616538913897268074355708519294930541905497969678255915008.000000) your price is -92559631349317830736831783200707727132248687965119994463780864.000000Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Doesn't seem like that solved anything.. just made it worse lol

Comment: Oh my bad, you also have a rogue bracket. I'll edit my post :).

Comment: There we go. Edited. I've tested this quickly and it looks like it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the early bracket was indeed the issue! ^^'

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept this as the answer if I helped :).